# Unable to launch photos library repair tool in macOS high sierra?

Tags: macos, photos, high-sierra

I was trying to launch the photos library repair tool by holding down option-command while opening photos. 
However this seems to be not working in macOS high sierra. 
Instead of repair tool, the photos app is opened.

I was referring to the instructions in the below link, to launch the repair tool: 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967

Has any one launched the repair tool in macOS high sierra?
Please advise how to launch the repair tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, this worked for me:

1. first open photo the library with only the option key held down
2. a popup appears asking you to select the photo library you want to work with, I found multiple libraries listed
3. I selected the photo library I wanted to fix
4. After it opens, close down photos and retry double clicking  photos icon holding down with the option & command keys held down.